# Is it still possible to use log4j remote logging?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I found some quite old examples online that allow use the org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.server.TcpSocketServer for remote logging (see https://github.com/piruin/log4j2-socket-server ). Unfortunately, it appears the class got removed or moved in updated versions.

How can I archive remote logging with log4j these days? Any tutorials available?

Comment: Do you want the part that your application uses to write messages to a remote destination, or do you something that implements the destination? If the latter, are you planning to manage the log messages in a server (such as Elasticsearch), or just write them to files?

Comment: Actually, I'm looking into both sides. For the moment, I was thinking about the server side and I'm not sure if that TcpSocketServer is still available. Is there a better library and/or solution? The goal is to log any errors of my Java app (that uses log4j) to a server and on the server to a file maybe. In best case the server provides a webUI or so to view the submitted stack traces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client side, Log4J gives you multiple options:

- [SocketAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SocketAppender) sends messages using TCP or UDP.
- [HttpAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#HttpAppender) sends messages using HTTP POST messages.
- [SyslogAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender) sends messages in syslog format, using either TCP or UDP.

On the server side, you won't find anything in the Log4J library, but there are plenty of options:

- For "quick and dirty", you can use NetCat:

  ```
  nc -l 1234 > foo.log
  ```
- Syslog is available on any Linux system; you can set up a central server and write logs to files. Personally, I find it more trouble than it's worth.
- A better solution, if you want to run it yourself, is [fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/). This will require some configuration, but gives you a lot of flexibility and future expansion.
- There are also plenty of 3rd-party services, such as Loggly or DataDog, which will accept your log messages and give you a search engine interface to view them.